# Insertar mapa dinamico en HTML

Tags: php, html

Me gustaría poder insertar un mapa dinamico en mi aplicación.

Ahora mismo lo que tengo es una botón, el cual me lleva a google maps con la dirección dinámica que tengo, y la verdad que funciona sin problema

Ejemplo:

```html
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?php echo $row['direccion']; ?>">Direccion: <?php echo $row['direccion']; ?></a>
```

Lo que quiero ahora es crear un inframe de google maps pero que sea dinamico también, he trasteado un poco y he utilizado algo así, pero no funciona

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=<?php $row['direccion']; ?>" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas la api de google maps?

Comment: Estoy trasteando ahora con la api y he probado algo así: <iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<?php $_POST['direccion']; ?>&key=Mi_API_Key" allowfullscreen>
</iframe> Pero sigue sin funcionar: Invalid q parameter

Comment: Deberías añadir eso a la pregunta junto con el valor de `$_POST[‘direccion’]` (o mejor la url generada completa). Además, ¿no faltaría un `echo` o algo para que se escriba la dirección? Tal y como lo tienes ahora parece que no se escribiría y el valor de q estaría vacío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, mi problema era que no hacia un echo como bien me ha comentado Alvaro, dejo el código completo con la api para quien tenga la misma duda que tenia yo:

```html
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<?php echo $_POST['direccion']; ?>&key=MI_API_KEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```